# TDD with Xml datasource issue

Tags: c#, xml, tdd

I am running under a situation where one of my TDD with Xml datasource works fine but other throws an error "The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data", "Error details: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

EmployeeModule in config works fine but CategoryModule throws above error, CategoryModule works fine if we define on Arribute level like this 
`DataSource"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\Category.xml", "CategoryName", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]`

Here is the config settings

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EmployeeModule" connectionString="|DataDirectory|\\Employee.xml" providerName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML" />
<add name="CategoryModule" connectionString="|DataDirectory|\\Category.xml" providerName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML" />
</connectionStrings>
<microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
<dataSources>      
  <add name ="Name" connectionString="EmployeeModule" dataTableName="Name" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>      
  <add name ="CategoryName" connectionString="CategoryModule" dataTableName="CategoryName" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>      
</dataSources>
</microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
```

Does it mean that we cannot define multiple connection string for xml datasources? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but I'll answer it to help others wondering the same.

You are probably correct. [This MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.aspx#exampleToggle) shows how to access the data source from TestContext in test class (you must read down a bit). With multiple data sources the test framework cannot decide what data source to put in the TestContext.